# React Form combine

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Get & store an selected field value based on the dropdown select, as well as get an form fields. The dropdown & form fields are separate forms. How can I combine the both the separate form fields into one form and how can I store it to database?

Any idea Please....
Thank you For help

Answer (score 0):

You can store them as formData before sending to your backend/database. This might go something like this:

```
function formBody(){
    const initialValues = {
        value_from_dropdown: "",
        value_from_text_field: "",
    }
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);
    const handleDropDownValueChange = () => {
         event.persist();
         setValues((values) => ({
            ...values,
            value_from_dropdown: event.target.value,
         }));
    }
     const handleTextValueChange = () => {
         event.persist();
         setValues((values) => ({
            ...values,
            value_from_text_field: event.target.value,
         }));
    }
    const hanldeSubmit = (e) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('dropdown', values.value_from_dropdown);
        formData.append('textfield', values.value_from_text_field);

    
    // post data
    
    }
}
```